# Erlang read from StdIn without prompt

Tags: io, erlang, stdout, stdin

I just read Erlang's IO module, all the input functions start with a prompt().

I have a program A which pipes it's output to my Erlang program B, therefore making A's `stdout` to B's `stdin`.

How can I just read that stdIn  in a loop,
since I get a msg every Xms.

what I want is something like this

```
loop()->
  NewMsg = readStdIn() %% thats the function I am looking for
  do_something(NewMsg),
  loop.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I just read Erlang's IO module, all the input functions start with a prompt().

It looks like you can use `""` for the prompt.   Reading *line oriented* input from stdin:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

read_stdin() ->
    case io:get_line("") of
        eof ->
            init:stop(); 
        Line ->
            io:format("Read from stdin: ~s", [Line]),
            read_stdin()
    end.
```

In a bash shell:

```
~/erlang_programs$ erl -compile my.erl
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported

~/erlang_programs$ echo -e "hello\nworld" | erl -noshell -s my read_stdin
Read from stdin: hello
Read from stdin: world
~/erlang_programs$
```

See [Erlang How Do I...write a unix pipe program in Erlang](http://erlang.org/faq/how_do_i.html#idp32779088)?

Comment: yeah, and empty String seems to work for the prompt, I just thought there had to be another way